# How to have the algorithmicx comment symbol in algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I want to know how can I have the nice ▷ 
`$\triangleright$` comment symbol of `algorithmicx` in `algorithm2e`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) (section **11.4 to define comments**, p 35):

> `\SetKwComment{Comment}{<start>}{<end>}` defines a macro `\Comment{text comment}` which writes `text comment` between `<start>` and `<end>`. Note that `<start>` or `<end>` can be empty.
>
> It defines also `\Comment*{side comment text}` macro which allows to put comment on the same line as the code. This macro can take various option to control its behaviour:
>
> - `\Comment*[r]{side comment text}` put the end of line mark (`;` by default) and side comment text just after and right justified, then end the line. It is the default.
> - `\Comment*[l]{side comment text}` same thing but side comment text is left justified.
> - `\Comment*[h]{side comment text}` put side comment right after the text. No end of line mark is put, and line is not terminated (is up to you to put `\;` to end the line).
> - `\Comment*[f]{side comment text}` same as the previous one but with side comment text right justified.

Here's an example of the above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{$\triangleright$\ }{}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\Comment*[r]{Some comment}
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to reformat the comment font, you can adjust `\CommentSty`. In `algorithm2e` this is done via (for example) `\SetCommentSty{itshape}` to obtain an `\itshape` or *italics* comment.

---

Here is a corresponding example showing the default comment style in [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), taken directly from the [`algorithmicx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```