# How to make comment marker a long dash in algorithm2e package?

Tags: luatex, algorithm2e

Something strange with `algorithm2e` comment. I'd like to make the left marker of the comment be a long dash. Similar to \textemdash. I was following the answer given here [how-to-have-the-algorithmicx-comment-symbol-in-algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200730/how-to-have-the-algorithmicx-comment-symbol-in-algorithm2e) but instead of using a triangle marker as in the above link, I wanted instead to use `---`. But I can't get it to work. (Actually the example in the answer above, does not compile for me on TL 2016).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I try `\SetKwComment{comment}{\textemdash}{}`, I do not get what I expected. I get something else. MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

%now set comment left marker
\SetKwComment{comment}{\textemdash}{}
\begin{document}

This \textemdash\ is a test.

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlgoLined
  \eIf{true}
  {
     $x=1$ \comment*{Some comment}
  }
  {
     $x=0$
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Now

```
lualatex foo2.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo2.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty)
********************************************************
Package `algorithm2e' Release 5.1 -- october 19 2015 --
- algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr mailing list for announcement about releases
- algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package
subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'
- Author: Christophe Fiorio (christophe.fiorio@umontpellier.fr)
********************************************************
) (./foo2.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdf
tex.map}] (./foo2.aux))
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 1061 ({)
### bottom level
 631 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 2 rule, 31 glue, 59 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:21,3:10,4:4,5:26,6:61,7:71,8:14,9:47,10:3
</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx7.pfb></u
sr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/
local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/l
ocal/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on foo2.pdf (1 page, 54390 bytes).
Transcript written on foo2.log.
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am doing something wrong. How to obtain `---` for left comment marker? If I just write `\SetKwComment{comment}{---}{}` I get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And they are not the same. I want the dash that looks solid, like on the first line above.

TL 2016

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @daleif I did, it helped a little, but it is still not the long dash. I get very small dash. Actually, for lualatex, which is what I use, I was told `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is not needed any more. So I do not include it.

Comment: Then you might want to make it a lot more clear that you are using LuaLaTeX. I tend to stay away from it because of these problems/inconsistencies. I cannot help you further. BTW: have you tried `\textnormal{\textemdash}`? It seems from your image that the comment is in typewriter and an em-dash might not even exist in that font.

Comment: @daleif thanks, `\textnormal{\textemdash}` worked!  if you like to post this as answer will accept it. sorry I was not clear about lualatex, but I showed the command I used which is lualatex.

Comment: You should at least tag it as a `lualatex` question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I main issue might be that the monospace font(the comment seems to be typeset in a monospace font) does not have an emdash.

A simple remedy might be to use the one from the document font instead i.e. `\textnormal{\textemdash}` or something similar.